# column options in sharepoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column

For a list i created in sharepoint online:
On some of my columns, the drop down arrow only shows "column settings" 
While other columns show "A to Z", "Z to A", "Filter by", "Group by Contact" and "Column settings >"

Is there a setting i need to click so that the full options of "A to Z", "Z to A", "Filter by", "Group by Contact" and "Column settings >" appear?

Comment: What is the data type of the columns that only show "Column Settings"?

Comment: the columns are all "multiple lines of text" but some show the full settings while others do not.

Comment: Multi-line text fields typically can't be sorted or filtered. There must be something custom or unusual about those columns that can- did you make the columns yourself or did you use Site Columns?

Comment: Thank you for the info. I added the columns myself. I am also having an issue where in the form setting, it won't let me select "Use a custom form created in PowerApps (requires new list experience)" Do you know what would cause this? sorry....I have a lot of issues with this list.

Comment: The "New List Experience" is an option you can enable: [Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9). Once you enable it you should be able to use PowerApps with it.